# Connection to ip-camera without SDK

Tags: camera, ip, video-streaming, ip-camera

As I know every manufacturer provides an SDK for its IP-camera. Every SDK has a set of functions for connecting client to ip-camera, getting video stream and etc.
But is there any way to connect and get video stream to **ANY** IP-camera **without** using manufacturer's SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANY - In short No. It completely depends on the capabilities programmed into the camera itself. For security purposes, a camera may be programmed to only work with a specific NVR, or have some proprietary protocol that would require you to utilize their SDK.

You can, however, have an IP camera that has a built-in HTTP stream in one of the common streaming media formats:
MPeg-4
Real Media
Windows Media
etc.

If your camera outputs an MMS:// stream, you can connect to that using MediaElement and setting the source.

Often, the camera will only provide snap shots, which you can capture at a high rate and repaint/refresh your UI at a fast rate.  I'd advice taking a look at some of the open source projects like:
http://wpfcap.codeplex.com/

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays most of the camera is ONVIF supported. http://www.onvif.org/ 
You can google and find ONVIF library in PHP, C#, Android, and JAVA.